# php-fpm doesn't connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, apache, fatal-error, php

I'm trying to migrate from Apache mod_php to PHP-FPM.

I'm attempting to connect to a mySQL DB but it seems I am missing some functionality:

```
Line 43 -  mysql_connect(hostname, username, pwd);
```

I am getting the classic Fatal Error:

```
 Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in 
/var/www/vhosts/dev.test.local/htdocs/index.php on line 43
```

Now, in the my `phpinfo` there isn't the classic mysql Box.

I'm running Apache2 on Centos 5.6 with Php 5.3 (but I think that the PHP version doesn't matter).

How can I install the necessary libraries for PHP-FPM?

Do I need to recompile PHP?

Comment: Please run a `php -m` from the CLI and copy the output here.

Comment: PHP Warning:  Module 'mysql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[PHP Modules]
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
gmp
hash
iconv
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
mysql
mysqli
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
standard
tokenizer
xml
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]

Answer (score 2):

You just need to enable mysql in the php-fpm config.  You have enabled it for apache.  See /etc/php5/fpm directory

Update, im not familiar with CentOS file layout, but if it's somewhat standard, there might also be a conf.d directory and then you need to do set some softlinks, the point is that every way you can use PHP (cgi, cli, apache (mod_php) or php-fpm) has a seperate ini file (and/or .conf, depending on the linux flavor), I'm convinced mysql libs are there since you use them in apache.  So it can only be that you haven't enabled the mysql extension inside php.

don't forget to restart php-fpm after that.

Comment: Ok. I've tried to  enable mysql.so extension but the reload after fails.`Starting php-fpm: [21-Sep-2012 12:25:16] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  Module 'mysql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: and the phpinfo() doesn't change.

Comment: Ok, thats good. that means the module is there and PHP-fpm sees it. Apparently it's already bootstrapped somewhere for you, you could take that last change out.  Is your Apache configured for CGI mode ?  I would use nginx (with upstream server) along with php-fpm.  I don't think I ever did this in Apache, but you probably need to tell it it's not supposed to process php code using mod_php but instead hand it over to php_fpm.  But I think it's established that your libraries are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this, if you haven't already:

http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-nginx-with-php5-and-php-fpm-and-mysql-support-on-centos-6.0-p2

Have you installed the appropriate MySQL modules?

> yum install **php-fpm php-cli php-mysql** php-gd php-imap php-ldap php-odbc php-pear php-xml php-xmlrpc php-eaccelerator php-magickwand php-magpierss php-mbstring php-mcrypt php-mssql php-shout php-snmp php-soap php-tidy

Comment: yes i do. so , i've tried to reinstall the MySql module but YUM has nothing to do.